# Dividing data into quintiles using group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for a way to change my way in such a way that it sorts the data into quintiles instead of the top 5 and bottom 5. My current code looks like this:

```
CombData <- CombData %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(
    R=min_rank(Value),
    E_P = case_when(
      R < 6 ~ "5w",
      R > max(R, na.rm =TRUE) - 5 ~ "5b",
      TRUE  ~ NA_character_)
    ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Date, E_P)
```

My dataset is quite large therefore I will just provide sample data. The data I use is more complex and the code should, therefore, allow for varying lengths of the column Date and also for multiple values that are missing (NAs):

```
df <- data.frame( Date = c(rep("2010-01-31",16), rep("2010-02-28", 14)), Value=c(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,15),2))
```

Afterward, I would also like to test the minimum size of quintiles i.e. how many data points are minimum in each quintile in the entire dataset.

The expected output would look like this:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(14640, 14640, 14640, 14640, 
14640, 14640, 14640, 14640, 14640, 14640, 14640, 14640, 14640, 
14640, 14640, 14640, 14668, 14668, 14668, 14668, 14668, 14668, 
14668, 14668, 14668, 14668, 14668, 14668, 14668, 14668), class = "Date"), 
    Value = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 15, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 15, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), R = c(1L, 
    1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), S_P = c("Worst", "Worst", "Worst", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Best", 
    "Best", "Best", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Worst", "Worst", NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "Best", "Best", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What would be your expected output for this? What would be `E_P` for missing values?

Comment: Nothing. Missing values should be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you could use something like this with `quantile` :

```
library(dplyr)

out <- CombData %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(S_P = case_when(Value <= quantile(Value, 0.2, na.rm = TRUE) ~ 'Worst', 
                     Value >= quantile(Value, 0.8, na.rm = TRUE) ~ 'Best'))
```

You could change the value of `quantile` according to your preference.

---

To get minimum number of "Best" and "Worst" we can do :

```
out %>%
   count(Date, S_P) %>%
   na.omit() %>%
   ungroup()   %>%
   select(-Date)  %>%
   group_by(S_P) %>%
   top_n(-1, n)

#  S_P       n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 Best      2
#2 Worst     2
```

Comment: Would it be possible to check the minimum size of the quintiles?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you want to have "Best" and "Worst" of specific size?

Comment: No, I want to make sure that there is sufficient data in each quintile at any given point. I would, therefore, like to know how many are worst or best minimum. In the data sample provided I would like to know that the lowest number of worst is 2.

Comment: @peho15ae I have updated the answer. See if it is that you want.

Answer (score 1):

When I understand you correctly, you want to rank your column 'Value' and mark those with rank below the quantile 20% with "worst" and those above 80% with "best". After that you want a table.

You could use use `ave` for both, the `rank`ing and the `quantile` identification. The `quantile` function yields three groups, that you can identify with `findInterval`, code as a `factor` variable and label them at will. I'm not sure, though, which ranks should be included in the quantiles, I therefore make the `E_P` coding in two separate columns for comparison purposes.

```
dat2 <- within(dat, {
  R <- ave(Value, Date, FUN=function(x) rank(x, na.last="keep"))
  E_P <- ave(R, Date, FUN=function(x) {
    findInterval(x, quantile(R, c(.2, .8), na.rm=TRUE))
  })
  E_P.fac <- factor(E_P, labels=c("worst", NA, "best"))
})
dat2 <- dat2[order(dat2$Date, dat2$E_P), ]  ## order by date and E_P
```

#### Yields:

```
dat2
#          Date Value E_P.fac E_P    R
# 1  2010-01-31     1   worst   0  1.5
# 16 2010-01-31     1   worst   0  1.5
# 2  2010-01-31     2    <NA>   1  3.0
# 3  2010-01-31     3    <NA>   1  4.0
# 4  2010-01-31     4    <NA>   1  5.0
# 5  2010-01-31     5    <NA>   1  6.0
# 6  2010-01-31     6    <NA>   1  7.0
# 7  2010-01-31     7    <NA>   1  8.0
# 8  2010-01-31     8    best   2  9.0
# 9  2010-01-31     9    best   2 10.0
# 15 2010-01-31    15    best   2 11.0
# 10 2010-01-31    NA    <NA>  NA   NA
# 11 2010-01-31    NA    <NA>  NA   NA
# 12 2010-01-31    NA    <NA>  NA   NA
# 13 2010-01-31    NA    <NA>  NA   NA
# 14 2010-01-31    NA    <NA>  NA   NA
# 17 2010-02-28     2   worst   0  1.0
# 18 2010-02-28     3   worst   0  2.0
# 19 2010-02-28     4    <NA>   1  3.0
# 20 2010-02-28     5    <NA>   1  4.0
# 21 2010-02-28     6    <NA>   1  5.0
# 22 2010-02-28     7    <NA>   1  6.0
# 23 2010-02-28     8    <NA>   1  7.0
# 24 2010-02-28     9    <NA>   1  8.0
# 30 2010-02-28    15    best   2  9.0
# 25 2010-02-28    NA    <NA>  NA   NA
# 26 2010-02-28    NA    <NA>  NA   NA
# 27 2010-02-28    NA    <NA>  NA   NA
# 28 2010-02-28    NA    <NA>  NA   NA
# 29 2010-02-28    NA    <NA>  NA   NA
```

When I check the quintiles of the `R`ank column, it appears to be right.

```
quantile(dat2$R, c(.2, .8), na.rm=TRUE)
# 20% 80% 
# 2.8 8.2
```

After that you could just make a table to get the numbers of each category.

```
with(dat2, table(Date, E_P.fac))
#             E_P.fac
# Date         worst <NA> best
#   2010-01-31     2    6    3
#   2010-02-28     2    6    1
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2010-01-31", "2010-02-28"
), class = "factor"), Value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 15)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```